# Does this bishop sac when your knight is pinned to your queen have a name?

Tags: tactics, terminology, sacrifice, pins

This is a common tactic in various openings. It goes like this:

- A bishop pins your knight to your queen
- You sacrifice your bishop with check to attract the king forward
- You give a check with your "pinned" knight to win the bishop that pinned you

Here is an example:

```
[FEN "rn1qkb1r/pp3ppp/2p2n2/4p3/2BPP1b1/5N2/PPP3PP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 7"]

7. Bxf7+! Kxf7 8. Nxe5+ Kg8 9. Nxg4
```

Does this tactic have a name?

Comment: doesn't have a special name afaik like 'hook and ladder' but does appear  to be a combination of attraction, fork, pin, sacrifice, hanging piece (the pawn), [attacking f2 or f7](https://lichess.org/training/attackingF2F7). if it has a special name, then i wanna know. *clicks follow*. edit: to be more specific, i believe it's not an [absolute pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_(chess)#Types)

Answer (score 4):

Yes; this is called [attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attraction_(chess)).  In this position, the White bishop attracts the Black king to f7 in order for the f3 knight to give check on e5, [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(chess)) the king and bishop.  This combination wins White two pawns.

Comment: Is this the same as what PDB means by the [keyword](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/keywords.jsp?s=themes) "steering" (Ger.: Lenkung)?